# How can I import bookmarks from Lightning into Firefox?

Tags: firefox-for-android, bookmarks, import

Previously I used Lightning as browser on my phone and I've bookmarked lotta pages in it. I started to use Firefox, because Lightning is very buggy. So, how can I import bookmarks from Lightning into Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a backup of your bookmarks in Lightning Browser:

1. Go to browser settings
2. Bookmark settings
3. Export Bookmarks to backup

It will create a backup of your all bookmarks in the Lighting browser. You can access it in File Explorer.

For importing bookmarks in the Firefox browser:

1. Menu button (either below the screen on some devices or at the top-right corner of the browser)
2. Select Settings
3. Tap on Advanced and then Import from Android
4. Browse and select that lighting bookmark backup file
5. Tap Import

Comment: I don't see a customize button in Firefox: https://i.imgur.com/VJLx94a.png

Comment: instead of customize you can tap on Advanced and then import option but that will import only native browser history and bookmarks. for better solution of this you can create a firefox account and then login with the same account & there you will see - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4att8Gy0BHUODZhU01IS0FTWEE  tap on import  bookmarks from html and then browser and select that backup file of your bookmarks. That's it , you're good to go.

Comment: I don't see an import button in "Advanced": https://i.imgur.com/NJqrSBt.jpg. Btw I don't wanna make a Firefox account…

Comment: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-BBZrwsIdFy0/WCF23Cs1BvI/AAAAAAAAAA8/IpZtH-CxtjcOCIGEjuV3Su3zpSwLtGASQCL0B/h1280/857683198181969229%253Faccount_id%253D1   .. you may scroll a little bit downwards ..check that .

Comment: That scrolling screenshot contains every option I see in the "Advanced" menu…

Comment: it's kinda weird but you can check you firefox update or skip this step, its much better that you follow importing into pc and sync it in to your firefox account that is the only way you can do it as far now. and creating firefox account is not hassle, it's just 2 step process..

Comment: I have the latest Firefox version. I know creating a Firefox account isn't a hassle, but I just don't want a Firefox account. Is there really not another way as using a Firefox account?

Comment: no there's no  other way you can do it in android firefox  though you can do it in pc without firefox account .